# Send Variable arguments for Java execution using Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have a build.xml where I have a target as follows:

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
        <arg value="${arg0}" />
        <arg value="${arg1}" />
        <arg value="${arg2}" />
        <arg value="${arg3}" />
        <arg value="${arg4}" />
        <arg value="${arg5}" />
        <arg value="${arg6}" />
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath" />
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

However I pass the arguments as :- ant -Darg0=XY -Darg1=ZX -Darg2=Sh -Darg3=RPR -Darg4=g -Darg5=t -Darg6=TC main. If I need to pass more variables then I will need to add argument field to the java tag in the run target as  and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I know the number of variable arguments that can be passed to the jar file. So I keep creating  elements. So for the above I had figured that the number of cases in use so I defined them as:-

```
<property name="arg0" value="..."/>
<property name="arg1" value="..."/>
<property name="arg2" value="..."/>
<property name="arg3" value="..."/>
...
```

Then I refer to them as:

```
<arg value="${arg0}" />
<arg value="${arg1}" />
<arg value="${arg2}" />
<arg value="${arg3}" />
...
```

To change the values in arg variables use :

```
ant -Darg0=value1 -Darg3=value2 run
```

Refer to the variable I appending -D to it.